# Free SMPP (jabber) libraries for .NET?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, dynamic, loadcontrol

I'm looking for a lightweight easy to use SMPP library for .NET.
Only requirement is that it must support Legacy SSL.

Any tips?

Comment: You mentioned Jabber: do you mean XMPP? SMPP is generally for sending text messages, while XMPP is a chat library.

Comment: Yes of course XMPP. I typo'ed ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Jabber (XMPP), I've known people that have used [agsXMPP SDK](http://www.ag-software.de/agsxmpp-sdk/) and have seemed to like it.

Comment: The search I've done hints that it does support legacy SSL. Despite what I was told, I did realize after looking through their site a bit more thoroughly that it may not be free depending on your application (or your conscience :) )

Comment: It will be only a small, personal application. This one is free, but its "follower" isn't. So it will be okay for me :) *approved*